# Replace a reflective call with a dynamically generated class

Tags: java, code-generation, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, byte-buddy

I have an interface similar to this:

```
public interface Getter {
    Object get(Params params);
}
```

that I implement using a reflective call to a different method:

```
public class GetterImpl implements Getter {

    private final Object target;
    private final Method method; //doStuff method

    public GetterImpl(Object target, Method method) {
        this.target = target;
        this.method = method;
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(Params params) {
        //both the target and arguments depend on Params
        return method.invoke(chooseTarget(params), prepareArgs(params));
    }

    private Object chooseTarget(Params params) {
        if (params.getTargetOverride() != null) {
            return params.getTargetOverride();
        }
        return target;
    }

    private Object[] prepareArgs(Params params) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to instead generate a class implementing `Getter` with equivalent logic but without reflection? Effectively a class like this:

```
public class GeneratedGetterImpl implements Getter {

    ...

    @Override
    public Object get(Params params) {
        //somehow call doStuff directly (different method for each generated impl)
        return target.doStuff(prepareArgs(params));
    }
}
```

I'm looking into using Byte Buddy to generate such a class on the fly, but all the examples provide some sort of statically known method interceptor, and never delegate to a dynamically chosen target and method.

It's clearly not a trivial task, but can this be done with Byte Buddy? Or a different library?

**UPDATE:**

Here's my best attempt so far:

```
Target target = new Target();
Method method = Target.class.getMethod("doStuff", Book.class);

//Helper class that computes the new arguments based on the original
Prepare prepare = new Prepare();
Method doPrep = Prepare.class.getMethod("doPrep", Params.class);

Getter getter = (Getter) new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Object.class)
            .implement(Getter.class)
            .method(named("get")).intercept(
                    MethodCall.invoke(method).on(target)
                            .withMethodCall(
                                    MethodCall.invoke(doPrep).on(prepare).withAllArguments()
                            ))
            .make()
            .load(getClass().getClassLoader())
            .getLoaded()
            .newInstance();

public static class Prepare {

    public Book doPrep(Params params) {
        return new Book(params.getTitle());
    }
}
```

This does what I want, but only if the targeted method takes 1 argument (`Book` in my case). I'm struggling to figure out how to have it return an array that I then *spread* when calling the target method.

E.g.

```
public static class Prepare {
    //returns all the arguments
    public Object[] doPrep(Params params) {
        return new Object[] { new Book(params.getTitle()) };
    }
}
```

Comment: You can call overloaded target methods based on input param, if all possible params are known.

Comment: You don't explain why you're trying to avoid reflection... but have you looked into generating a dynamic script of a language like Groovy?

Comment: Does you target method truly accept `Object[]` as parameter?

Comment: @Holger No, that was just for the sake of simplifying the example.

Comment: You can easily generate an implementation which invokes a particular target method, if the signature matches, but it’s getting far more complicated when you need to adapt the arguments.

Comment: Why exactly you need to do that? performance difference will be near 0, and it will only make stuff more complicated. You said that one of reasons is that you want to run it native with graal, but defining classes like that is not allowed on native platform.

Comment: @GotoFinal I can generate the classes during image preparation. This is a technique Quarkus employs a lot. And they use a library called Gizmo, which is likely what I'll likely do in the end. Byte Buddy is clearly not intended for this sort of use.

Answer (score 6):

Such a facility does already exists in the JRE, if we restrict it to binding an interface to a matching target method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    Function<Double,Double> f1 = create(Math.class.getMethod("abs", double.class));
    System.out.println(f1.apply(-42.0));

    Map<Double,Double> m = new HashMap<>();
    Function<Double,Double> f2 = create(Map.class.getMethod("get", Object.class), m);
    m.put(1.0, 123.0);
    System.out.println(f2.apply(1.0));
}

static Function<Double,Double> create(Method m) {
    MethodHandles.Lookup l = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodType t = MethodType.methodType(Double.class, Double.class);
    try {
        return (Function)LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(l, "apply",
                MethodType.methodType(Function.class), t.erase(), l.unreflect(m), t)
                .getTarget().invoke();
    } catch(Throwable ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
}
static Function<Double,Double> create(Method m, Object target) {
    MethodHandles.Lookup l = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodType t = MethodType.methodType(Double.class, Double.class);
    try {
        return (Function)LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(l, "apply",
                MethodType.methodType(Function.class, m.getDeclaringClass()),
                t.erase(), l.unreflect(m), t)
                .getTarget().invoke(target);
    } catch(Throwable ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
}
```

```
42.0
123.0
```

This demonstrates that adaptations like auto-boxing and casting as required for generic functions are included, but any other adaptations of parameters or results are not possible and have to be performed by pre-existing decorating code. Most notably, varargs processing is not included.

[The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) is exhaustive. It’s strongly recommended to read it in all details before using the class. But the things you can do wrong here, are similar to the things you can do wrong when implementing your own bytecode generator.

Comment: Thanks for this! I managed to replace my original code with a `MethodHandle` based one. I now have to understand if/how this plays along with Graal/SubstrateVM, as one of the reasons I'm investigating this is to potentially gain the ability to run it natively (without the reflection descriptors as they're very difficult to make use of in my insanely dynamic scenarios).

Answer (score 1):

Using Byte Buddy, you can create a `MethodCall` instance that represents your proxied method and use it as an implementation. I assume that you looked into delegation which requires a more static model:

```
MethodCall.invoke(SomeClass.class.getMethod("foo")).with(...)
```

You can also provide other method call instances as arguments to methods to achieve what you have in your example code.

As for your updated question, I'd recommend you a hybrid approach. Implement some container:

```
class Builder<T> {
  Builder with<T>(T value);
  T[] toArray();
}
```

and then you can use Byte Buddy to invoke it for creating your result value:

```
MethodCall builder = MethodCall.construct(Builder.class.getConstructor());
for (SomeInfoObject info : ...) {
  builder = MethodCall.invoke(Builder.class.getMethod("with", Object.class))
                      .on(builder)
                      .with(toMethodCall(info));
}
builder = MethodCall.invoke(Builder.class.getMethod("toArray")).on(builder);
```

Byte Buddy's goal is to make weaving code easy, not to replace writing static code which is the much better option if you have the opportunity.

Comment: Thanks, Rafael! I managed to get something working (updated the question for the benefit of others). Looking into making it prettier now.

Comment: Gah, spoke too soon. My approach only works for a single argument. I'm still struggling to understand how to _spread_ and argument array when calling the proxied method. Please see my updated question.

Comment: That's not really possible with the API where no variables are assigned. You can however implement your own byte code by using the byte code-level API directly. Or have a look at Advice where you can write byte code templates using regular Java code. Method handles do however seem like the more feasible option here.If you want to use Byte Buddy, it is of course however possible. I updated my answer.